# Web Scraping a tableauViz into an R dataframe

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, tableau-api

I have spent a lot of time searching for an answer to this, but have not found anything yet. What I am trying to accomplish is to scrape Tableau table information that is contained in a tableauViz element and propagate it into an R dataframe. In my first attempt, using RStudio, I employed the following code and tried to read the tableauViz as HTML

```
# Load rvest functions
library(rvest)
# Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- “https://oir.uga.edu/factbook/studentinformation/S07StuP58/”
# Reading the HTML code from the website                                          
webpage <- read_html(url)  
# Using CSS selectors to scrap the rankings section                                                     
rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.tableauViz')
```

The output was formatted as an xml_nodeset list as follows.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "\n                                    "

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "host_url"
attr(,"value")
[1] "https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "site_root"
attr(,"value")
[1] ""

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "name"
attr(,"value")
[1] "S07StuP58/Dashboard1"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "tabs"
attr(,"value")
[1] "no"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "toolbar"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "static_image"
attr(,"value")
[1] "https://public.tableau.com/static/images/S0/S07StuP58/Dashboard1/1.png"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "animate_transition"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "display_static_image"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "display_spinner"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "display_overlay"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "display_count"
attr(,"value")
[1] "yes"

[[1]]$param
list()
attr(,"name")
[1] "filter"
attr(,"value")
[1] "publish=yes"

attr(,".class")
[1] "tableauViz"
attr(,"style")
[1] "display:none;"
```

The only attribute from that list that I found of value was the static image png link.

[Tableau Static png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omy9Z.jpg)

However, I don’t believe I’ll be able to convert any of that into a dataframe.

The only reference to this issue was this excellent YouTube Video “Integrating Tableau with R through R Notebooks and Shiny”. I navigated to the author’s [GitHub site](https://github.com/fissehab?tab=repositories) to see if I could find some sample code but I was unable to locate any.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps it's none of my business but the author intentionally published that workbook on Tableau Public with the restriction of only allowing a PDF or PNG download. You are asking us to provide a way to circumvent the author's intended use of the data. That being said, what you are trying to accomplish is very difficult to do as Tableau visualizations aren't simply html. It's a very complicated use of AJAX, client-side rendering and SVG. You might be better off contacting the person who published the workbook and asking if they would be willing to share the data with you.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the data, you need the tableau URL which is in this case :

https://public.tableau.com/views/S07StuP58/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no

The flow is the following :

- call the following url :

  ```
  GET https://public.tableau.com/views/S07StuP58/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no
  ```
- extract the JSON content from the `textarea` with id `tsConfigContainer`
- build the url with the session_id

  ```
  POST https://public.tableau.com/{vizql_path}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{session_id}
  ```
- extract the JSON data from the response which is not JSON originally (regex to split the data)
- extract the data from the large JSON configuration, this is not straightforward since all the strings data are located in a single array. You need to get the data indices from various fields in order to be able to split the data into columns and then build your dataframe

The following code will prompt the user to choose a worksheet (by index), parse the data and put it in a dataframe :

```
library(rvest)
library(rjson)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

#replace the hostname and the path if necessary
host_url <- "https://public.tableau.com"
path <- "/views/S07StuP58/Dashboard1"

body <- read_html(modify_url(host_url, 
                             path = path, 
                             query = list(":embed" = "y",":showVizHome" = "no")
))

data <- body %>% 
  html_nodes("textarea#tsConfigContainer") %>% 
  html_text()
json <- fromJSON(data)

url <- modify_url(host_url, path = paste(json$vizql_root, "/bootstrapSession/sessions/", json$sessionid, sep =""))

resp <- POST(url, body = list(sheet_id = json$sheetId), encode = "form")
data <- content(resp, "text")

extract <- str_match(data, "\\d+;(\\{.*\\})\\d+;(\\{.*\\})")
info <- fromJSON(extract[1,1])
data <- fromJSON(extract[1,3])

worksheets = names(data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$vizData$presModelHolder$genPresModelMapPresModel$presModelMap)

for(i in 1:length(worksheets)){
  print(paste("[",i,"] ",worksheets[i], sep=""))
}
selected <-  readline(prompt="select worksheet by index: ");
worksheet <- worksheets[as.integer(selected)]
print(paste("you selected :", worksheet, sep=" "))

columnsData <- data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$vizData$presModelHolder$genPresModelMapPresModel$presModelMap[[worksheet]]$presModelHolder$genVizDataPresModel$paneColumnsData

i <- 1
result <- list();
for(t in columnsData$vizDataColumns){
  if (is.null(t[["fieldCaption"]]) == FALSE) {
    paneIndex <- t$paneIndices
    columnIndex <- t$columnIndices
    if (length(t$paneIndices) > 1){
      paneIndex <- t$paneIndices[1]
    }
    if (length(t$columnIndices) > 1){
      columnIndex <- t$columnIndices[1]
    }
    result[[i]] <- list(
      fieldCaption = t[["fieldCaption"]], 
      valueIndices = columnsData$paneColumnsList[[paneIndex + 1]]$vizPaneColumns[[columnIndex + 1]]$valueIndices,
      aliasIndices = columnsData$paneColumnsList[[paneIndex + 1]]$vizPaneColumns[[columnIndex + 1]]$aliasIndices, 
      dataType = t[["dataType"]],
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
dataFull = data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$dataDictionary$presModelHolder$genDataDictionaryPresModel$dataSegments[["0"]]$dataColumns

cstring <- list();
for(t in dataFull) {
  if(t$dataType == "cstring"){
    cstring <- t
    break
  }
}
data_index <- 1
name_index <- 1
frameData <-  list()
frameNames <- c()
for(t in dataFull) {
  for(index in result) {
    if (t$dataType == index["dataType"]){
      if (length(index$valueIndices) > 0) {
        j <- 1
        vector <- character(length(index$valueIndices))
        for (it in index$valueIndices){
          vector[j] <- t$dataValues[it+1]
          j <- j + 1
        }
        frameData[[data_index]] <- vector
        frameNames[[name_index]] <- paste(index$fieldCaption, "value", sep="-")
        data_index <- data_index + 1
        name_index <- name_index + 1
      }
      if (length(index$aliasIndices) > 0) {
        j <- 1
        vector <- character(length(index$aliasIndices))
        for (it in index$aliasIndices){
          if (it >= 0){
            vector[j] <- t$dataValues[it+1]
          } else {
            vector[j] <- cstring$dataValues[abs(it)]
          }
          j <- j + 1
        }
        frameData[[data_index]] <- vector
        frameNames[[name_index]] <- paste(index$fieldCaption, "alias", sep="-")
        data_index <- data_index + 1
        name_index <- name_index + 1
      }
    }
  }
}

df <- NULL
lengthList <- c()
for(i in 1:length(frameNames)){
  lengthList[i] <- length(frameData[[i]])
}
max <- max(lengthList)
for(i in 1:length(frameNames)){
  if (length(frameData[[i]]) < max){
    len <- length(frameData[[i]])
    frameData[[i]][(len+1):max]<-""
  }
  df[frameNames[[i]]] <- frameData[i]
}
options(width = 1200)
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df)
```

which gives the following output :

```
               X.Student.Aid.Program.Type..value               X.Student.Aid.Program..value        X..Measure.Names..alias X.Multiple.Values..alias
1                            Grants/Scholarships                                   Subtotal        Graduate Amount Awarded             $XXXXXXXX
2                            Grants/Scholarships       Other (External) Grants/Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded                 $XXXXXX
3                            Grants/Scholarships Miscellaneous Tuition/Fee Payments/Waivers        Graduate Amount Awarded              $XXXXXX
4                            Grants/Scholarships     Graduate Assistantship Tuition Waivers        Graduate Amount Awarded              $XXXXXX
5                            Grants/Scholarships                      Athletic Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded                 $XXXXXX
6                            Grants/Scholarships          Institutional Grants/Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded               $XXXXXX
7                            Grants/Scholarships          State (Other) Grants/Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded                   $XXXXXX
8                            Grants/Scholarships                   Zell Miller Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded               $XXXXXX
9                            Grants/Scholarships                          HOPE Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded                 $XXXXXX
10                           Grants/Scholarships        Federal (Other) Grants/Scholarships        Graduate Amount Awarded                         
11                           Grants/Scholarships                Federal Supplemental Grants        Graduate Amount Awarded                         
12                           Grants/Scholarships                        Federal Pell Grants        Graduate Amount Awarded                         
13                           Grants/Scholarships                                   Subtotal      Graduate Number of Awards                    XXXXXX
14                           Grants/Scholarships       Other (External) Grants/Scholarships      Graduate Number of Awards                      XXX
```

The [python](/questions/tagged/python) equivalent of the code above would be :

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import pandas as pd

#replace the hostname and the path if necessary
host_url = "https://public.tableau.com"
path = "/views/S07StuP58/Dashboard1"

url = f"{host_url}{path}"

r = requests.get(
    url,
    params= {
        ":embed": "y",
        ":showVizHome": "no"
    }
) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'{host_url}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'

r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

worksheets = list(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"].keys())

for idx, ws in enumerate(worksheets):
    print(f"[{idx}] {ws}")

selected = input("select worksheet by index: ")
worksheet = worksheets[int(selected)]
print(f"you selected : {worksheet}")

columnsData = data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"][worksheet]["presModelHolder"]["genVizDataPresModel"]["paneColumnsData"]
result = [ 
    {
        "fieldCaption": t.get("fieldCaption", ""), 
        "valueIndices": columnsData["paneColumnsList"][t["paneIndices"][0]]["vizPaneColumns"][t["columnIndices"][0]]["valueIndices"],
        "aliasIndices": columnsData["paneColumnsList"][t["paneIndices"][0]]["vizPaneColumns"][t["columnIndices"][0]]["aliasIndices"],
        "dataType": t.get("dataType"),
        "paneIndices": t["paneIndices"][0],
        "columnIndices": t["columnIndices"][0]
    }
    for t in columnsData["vizDataColumns"]
    if t.get("fieldCaption")
]
dataFull = data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"]

def onAlias(it, value, cstring):
    return value[it] if (it >= 0) else cstring["dataValues"][abs(it)-1]

frameData = {}
cstring = [t for t in dataFull if t["dataType"] == "cstring"][0]
for t in dataFull:
    for index in result:
        if (t["dataType"] == index["dataType"]):
            if len(index["valueIndices"]) > 0:
                frameData[f'{index["fieldCaption"]}-value'] = [t["dataValues"][abs(it)] for it in index["valueIndices"]]
            if len(index["aliasIndices"]) > 0:
                frameData[f'{index["fieldCaption"]}-alias'] = [onAlias(it, t["dataValues"], cstring) for it in index["aliasIndices"]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(frameData, orient='index').fillna(0).T
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', 1000):
    print(df)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeTableauSingleTable)

[checkout this repo](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) for both script in python and R