# How do I scrape tableau data from website into R?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, tableau-api

I'm working on a project that currently requires me to visit this website (https://returntogrounds.virginia.edu/covid-tracker) every day, and manually add each new day's `date` and `UVA positive cases` value to a data frame. Is there a code I can run in R that would create a data frame of `date` and `UVA positive cases` rather than me having to manually add the new data every day? I see that there is [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095206/how-to-scrape-a-public-tableau-dashboard) but this is for python which I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to get the tableau URL which is :

https://public.tableau.com/views/UVACOVIDTracker/Summary?&:embed=y&:showVizHome=no

From there, you need to execute the following flow (same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200637/2614364)):

- call the following url :

  ```
  GET https://public.tableau.com/views/S07StuP58/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no
  ```
- extract the JSON content from the `textarea` with id `tsConfigContainer`
- build the url with the session_id

  ```
  POST https://public.tableau.com/{vizql_path}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{session_id}
  ```
- extract the JSON data from the response which is not JSON originally (regex to split the data)
- extract the data from the large JSON configuration, this is not straightforward since all the strings data are located in a single array. You need to get the data indices from various fields in order to be able to split the data into columns and then build your dataframe

There are many "worksheets" on this view so I've made a script which prompt user to select one, so you can check which one is more convenient for you :

```
library(rvest)
library(rjson)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

#replace the hostname and the path if necessary
host_url <- "https://public.tableau.com"
path <- "/views/UVACOVIDTracker/Summary"

body <- read_html(modify_url(host_url, 
                             path = path, 
                             query = list(":embed" = "y",":showVizHome" = "no")
))

data <- body %>% 
  html_nodes("textarea#tsConfigContainer") %>% 
  html_text()
json <- fromJSON(data)

url <- modify_url(host_url, path = paste(json$vizql_root, "/bootstrapSession/sessions/", json$sessionid, sep =""))

resp <- POST(url, body = list(sheet_id = json$sheetId), encode = "form")
data <- content(resp, "text")

extract <- str_match(data, "\\d+;(\\{.*\\})\\d+;(\\{.*\\})")
info <- fromJSON(extract[1,1])
data <- fromJSON(extract[1,3])

worksheets = names(data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$vizData$presModelHolder$genPresModelMapPresModel$presModelMap)

for(i in 1:length(worksheets)){
  print(paste("[",i,"] ",worksheets[i], sep=""))
}
selected <-  readline(prompt="select worksheet by index: ");
worksheet <- worksheets[as.integer(selected)]
print(paste("you selected :", worksheet, sep=" "))

columnsData <- data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$vizData$presModelHolder$genPresModelMapPresModel$presModelMap[[worksheet]]$presModelHolder$genVizDataPresModel$paneColumnsData

i <- 1
result <- list();
for(t in columnsData$vizDataColumns){
  if (is.null(t[["fieldCaption"]]) == FALSE) {
    paneIndex <- t$paneIndices
    columnIndex <- t$columnIndices
    if (length(t$paneIndices) > 1){
      paneIndex <- t$paneIndices[1]
    }
    if (length(t$columnIndices) > 1){
      columnIndex <- t$columnIndices[1]
    }
    result[[i]] <- list(
      fieldCaption = t[["fieldCaption"]], 
      valueIndices = columnsData$paneColumnsList[[paneIndex + 1]]$vizPaneColumns[[columnIndex + 1]]$valueIndices,
      aliasIndices = columnsData$paneColumnsList[[paneIndex + 1]]$vizPaneColumns[[columnIndex + 1]]$aliasIndices, 
      dataType = t[["dataType"]],
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
dataFull = data$secondaryInfo$presModelMap$dataDictionary$presModelHolder$genDataDictionaryPresModel$dataSegments[["0"]]$dataColumns

cstring <- list();
for(t in dataFull) {
  if(t$dataType == "cstring"){
    cstring <- t
    break
  }
}
data_index <- 1
name_index <- 1
frameData <-  list()
frameNames <- c()
for(t in dataFull) {
  for(index in result) {
    if (t$dataType == index["dataType"]){
      if (length(index$valueIndices) > 0) {
        j <- 1
        vector <- character(length(index$valueIndices))
        for (it in index$valueIndices){
          vector[j] <- t$dataValues[it+1]
          j <- j + 1
        }
        frameData[[data_index]] <- vector
        frameNames[[name_index]] <- paste(index$fieldCaption, "value", sep="-")
        data_index <- data_index + 1
        name_index <- name_index + 1
      }
      if (length(index$aliasIndices) > 0) {
        j <- 1
        vector <- character(length(index$aliasIndices))
        for (it in index$aliasIndices){
          if (it >= 0){
            vector[j] <- t$dataValues[it+1]
          } else {
            vector[j] <- cstring$dataValues[abs(it)]
          }
          j <- j + 1
        }
        frameData[[data_index]] <- vector
        frameNames[[name_index]] <- paste(index$fieldCaption, "alias", sep="-")
        data_index <- data_index + 1
        name_index <- name_index + 1
      }
    }
  }
}

df <- NULL
lengthList <- c()
for(i in 1:length(frameNames)){
  lengthList[i] <- length(frameData[[i]])
}
max <- max(lengthList)
for(i in 1:length(frameNames)){
  if (length(frameData[[i]]) < max){
    len <- length(frameData[[i]])
    frameData[[i]][(len+1):max]<-""
  }
  df[frameNames[[i]]] <- frameData[i]
}
options(width = 1200)
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df)
```

Contrary to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200637/2614364) the `dataType` field needs to be the same as the one from the field from `presModelHolder$genVizDataPresModel$paneColumnsData` (which describes all indices in each column)

Output of this script:

```
Loading required package: xml2
[1] "[1] Active inpatient"
[1] "[2] Employee tests 2 weeks ago"
[1] "[3] Employee tests last week"
[1] "[4] Hosp all line"
[1] "[5] Hosp yesterday"
[1] "[6] Pos all UVA count line"
[1] "[7] Pos all UVA total"
[1] "[8] Pos student count line"
[1] "[9] Pos student total"
[1] "[10] Resources"
[1] "[11] Room isolation bar"
[1] "[12] Room quarantine bar"
[1] "[13] Student cases yesterday"
[1] "[14] Student new case 10-day total"
[1] "[15] Student test last week"
[1] "[16] Student tests 2 weeks ago"
[1] "[17] Tests UVA Lab TAT"
[1] "[18] Title"
[1] "[19] UVA 2 weeks ago"
[1] "[20] UVA Cases 10 subtotal"
[1] "[21] UVA Cases yesterday"
[1] "[22] UVA tests - last week"
[1] "[23] avg cases - 2 wks ago"
[1] "[24] avg cases - 3 wks ago"
[1] "[25] avg cases - last wk"
[1] "[26] avg new cases - this week"
[1] "[27] avg student cases - 2 weeks ago"
[1] "[28] avg student cases - 3 weeks ago"
[1] "[29] avg student cases - last week"
[1] "[30] avg student cases - this week"
select worksheet by index: 6
[1] "you selected : Pos all UVA count line"
   X.Calculation_246290626693455872..value X.Event_Date..value
1                                       29 2020-10-01 00:00:00
2                                       33 2020-09-30 00:00:00
3                                       45 2020-09-29 00:00:00
4                                        4 2020-09-28 00:00:00
5                                       17 2020-09-27 00:00:00
6                                       23 2020-09-26 00:00:00
7                                       41 2020-09-25 00:00:00
..............................................................
40                                       2 2020-08-23 00:00:00
41                                       5 2020-08-22 00:00:00
42                                       3 2020-08-21 00:00:00
43                                       5 2020-08-20 00:00:00
44                                       3 2020-08-19 00:00:00
45                                       4 2020-08-18 00:00:00
46                                       4 2020-08-17 00:00:00
```

I've notived that the worksheet that would work would be "Pos all UVA count line" and "Pos student count line"

The same script written in [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import pandas as pd

#replace the hostname and the path if necessary
host_url = "https://public.tableau.com"
path = "/views/UVACOVIDTracker/Summary"

url = f"{host_url}{path}"

r = requests.get(
    url,
    params= {
        ":embed": "y",
        ":showVizHome": "no"
    }
) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'{host_url}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'

r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

worksheets = list(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"].keys())

for idx, ws in enumerate(worksheets):
    print(f"[{idx}] {ws}")

selected = input("select worksheet by index: ")
worksheet = worksheets[int(selected)]
print(f"you selected : {worksheet}")

columnsData = data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["vizData"]["presModelHolder"]["genPresModelMapPresModel"]["presModelMap"][worksheet]["presModelHolder"]["genVizDataPresModel"]["paneColumnsData"]
result = [ 
    {
        "fieldCaption": t.get("fieldCaption", ""), 
        "valueIndices": columnsData["paneColumnsList"][t["paneIndices"][0]]["vizPaneColumns"][t["columnIndices"][0]]["valueIndices"],
        "aliasIndices": columnsData["paneColumnsList"][t["paneIndices"][0]]["vizPaneColumns"][t["columnIndices"][0]]["aliasIndices"],
        "dataType": t.get("dataType"),
        "paneIndices": t["paneIndices"][0],
        "columnIndices": t["columnIndices"][0]
    }
    for t in columnsData["vizDataColumns"]
    if t.get("fieldCaption")
]
dataFull = data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"]

def onAlias(it, value, cstring):
    return value[it] if (it >= 0) else cstring["dataValues"][abs(it)-1]

frameData = {}
cstring = [t for t in dataFull if t["dataType"] == "cstring"][0]
for t in dataFull:
    for index in result:
        if (t["dataType"] == index["dataType"]):
            if len(index["valueIndices"]) > 0:
                frameData[f'{index["fieldCaption"]}-value'] = [t["dataValues"][abs(it)] for it in index["valueIndices"]]
            if len(index["aliasIndices"]) > 0:
                frameData[f'{index["fieldCaption"]}-alias'] = [onAlias(it, t["dataValues"], cstring) for it in index["aliasIndices"]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(frameData, orient='index').fillna(0).T
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', 1000):
    print(df)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauScrapingPromptWorksheet)

Edit: I've improved the scripts to include the alias values which gives more data

I've made a repo including Python and R script [here](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping)

Answer (score 1):

Lookup rvest/xml2 for scraping parseable HTML.  Unfortunately, with Tableau/PowerBI applications, this is not straight-forward.  With pages such as this with built objects, accessing the underlying data is preferable.

The other answer you highlight is on the right track.  Get the JSON formatted data (usually from an API request) and extract the values you want.  However, another problem you will find is that the session ID is not persistent.  You may need to capture all the XHR objects when you visit the page's URL and then go through some messy logic to identify the right object.

(If you need to view all the resources accessed in the page visit, press F12 in your browser, and go to the 'Network' tab.)

At this stage, it probably wouldn't hurt to ask the Tableau authors if the API is publicly available, or if they can offer a dataset download capability in the report.

Good luck.