# How do you scrape data off of a public Tableau with multiple data visualizations?

Tags: r, tableau-api, scrape

I am trying to obtain COVID deaths for each county in the US by race and ethnicity. However, the North Carolina website does not have an option to download a .CSV file and instead houses their data in Tableau data visualizations. Any help on how to transform information in the data visualizations into an R data table would be appreciated. I need the data for every county in the state. I have tried looking at other posts on this site but haven't been able to figure them out on my own.

https://public.tableau.com/profile/ncdhhs.covid19data#!/vizhome/NCDHHS_COVID-19_Dashboard_Cases_County/NCDHHS_Dashboard_Cases2

Thank you.

Comment: hello, you have sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094560/how-do-i-scrape-tableau-data-from-website-into-r/64201083#64201083) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226270/web-scraping-a-tableauviz-into-an-r-dataframe/64200637#64200637) for scraping tableau data with R

Comment: Government sites generally have the data available. You don't need to scrape it. Click around the site and you'll find this. https://covid19.ncdhhs.gov/dashboard/about-data. Scroll to the bottom where they provide the data for downloading.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. @BertrandMartel , the website does not allow for the download of deaths at the county level by race/ethnicity--this information is only available in the tableau visualizations. I am very unfamiliar with JSON and would appreciate more guidance.