# Tableau public vizualization data source from dashboard

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, datasource, stock

https://public.tableau.com/profile/jamesbond#!/vizhome/NiftyPERatio_16005774872610/NiftyPERatioHeatMap

How do I figure out the data source of this viz? I am trying to create my own similar visualisations, hence investigating what they are getting data.

Comment: It's possible to scrape the data (by reverse engineering the underlying JS api), check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52226270/2614364) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63025296/2614364)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't for thiz viz.

The author doesn't allow download for workbook and data.